# Should Vaishnavas live off fruits only?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, diet

From the [Ahara Niyamam](https://www.srivaishnavam.com/desikaprabandam/ahara_meaning.htm) of Sri Vaishnava acharya Vedanta Deshikan:

Prohibited foods:

> Products (grains, pulses etc.) not offered to God after the harvest

Prohibited dairy products:

> Milk of cow that has given birth to twin calves
>
> Cow that is pregnant and cow just ready for sexual intercourse
>
> The milk of a cow whose calf had just died
>
> Milk drawn from a cow by showing to it a calf of another cow
>
> Milk of cows bearing names of deities other than those of Sriman
> Narayana
>
> Milk of a cow that has just delivered for at
> least 10 days after delivery

Prohibitions on water:

> Except Ganges water, no stored up water standing over a day should be used.

Can we verify that grains harvested in India, and/or grains imported from foreign countries are offered to Lord Vishnu after the harvest? This means Vaishnavas should not eat grains.

And the modern dairy industry also does not follow the milking process above, so does this means Vaishnavas should go vegan? In fact, give up all foods except raw vegetables and fruits?

The modern water plumbing system also stores water for long periods time in tanks. Does this mean Vaishnavas shouldn't drink tap water either?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137271/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-should-vaishnavas-live-off-fruits-only).